# Magento onepage issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

HI, i have 1.4.2 ver, and i have issue with onepage checkout page.
When I am on Ship Method tab and I click Next, NOTHING happen... I use free shipping for test.

under firebug i can see this:

`http://www.mysite.com/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/  200 ok 1.53s`

but i can't go on the next tab ( Payment info )..
Plaese can anyone help me?

Comment: In firebug click that entry to expand it, then look at it's "Response" and you will probably see a PHP error report. Use that as a clue or paste it here for all to see.

Comment: under html: {"goto_section":"payment","update_section":{"name":"payment-method","html":null}}, answer: {"goto_section":"payment","update_section":{"name":"payment-method","html":null}}.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your locale.

You are using some local language, and you didn't save the translation (`translate.csv`) for it in UTF-8